# Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread error when not using @Configuration. In what case @Configuration is required?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Created an application using Spring and hibernate using Java configuration. Though there are solutions provided for this error, but I couldn't understand the relation between @Configuration and HibernateException. In my code I've used @EnableTransactionManager and @Transaction on Services.

Below is the code:

AppInitializer.java

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{HibernateConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

SpringConfiguration.java

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.o2o.project")
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="jspViewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolvers(){

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }


}
```

HibernateConfiguration.java

```
 @EnableTransactionManagement
    @PropertySource(value={"classpath:database.properties"})
    public class HibernateConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;

        @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.o2o.project.model" });
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        @Bean(name="dataSource")
        public DataSource dataSource(){
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("database.driver"));
            dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("database.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("database.user"));
            dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("database.password"));
            return dataSource;
        }

        private Properties hibernateProperties(){
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
            properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            return properties;        
        }

        @Bean(name="transactionManager")
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
            return transactionManager;
        }

    }
```

EmployeeServiceImpl.java

```
@Service("employeeService")
@Transactional
public class EmployeeServiceImp implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAD;

    @Override
    public void addEmployee(EmployeeModel employeeModel) {
        employeeDAD.addEmployee(employeeModel);
    }

    @Override
    public List<EmployeeModel> list() {
        return employeeDAD.list();
    }

    @Override
    public EmployeeModel searchEmployee(int employeeID) {
        return employeeDAD.searchEmployee(employeeID);
    }

}
```

**Case 1** 
If I am annotating the class HibernateConfiguration with "@Configuration/@Component" then it is working without throwing any exception otherwise I am getting HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread.

**Case 2**
Even tried adding the beans defined in HibernateConfiguration class in SpringConfiguration as below, code is working fine without annotating SpringConfiguration with @Configuration:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.o2o.project")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:database.properties"})
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="jspViewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolvers(){

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.o2o.project.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("database.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("database.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("database.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("database.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Even if I am not annotating SpringConfiguration.class mentioned in getServletConfigClasses() of AppInitializer with @Configuration, it is working fine. In most of the documents I came across, it is mentioned @Configuration is used when defininig more than @Bean in a class, but it is working fine in case 2 without annotating with @Configuration.

Why am I getting the above exception when removing @Configuration/@Component. What and when @Configuration should be used? I am actually confused when @Configuration is required?

Answer (score 0):

Since your not using  spring-config xml file and below config tags

```
<beans>
        <context:annotation-config/>
        <bean class="yourpackge.HibernateConfiguration"/>
   </beans>
```

So you have to use `@Configuration` , then only your `@Bean` and `@Autowired` annotated methods will get bean definitions and service request at run time of your application.

In other Case where your having `getServletConfigClasses()` there your not having any `@Bean` or `@Autowired` annotanation so it not needed to annotanate with `@Configuration`

So its clearly mean that for any Bean definitions you need to have `@Configuration` and `@Component` annotanation

I think its clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Even tried the other way, by  adding the beans defined in HibernateConfiguration class in SpringConfiguration and removed HibernateConfiguration.java file - (Please refer case 2) . Still it was not required to annotate SpringConfiguration with @Configuration.

Comment: yes , But in **case 2**  you have annotated with _@ComponentScan_ in **SpringConfiguration** class , that will configure itself as a configuration class so you not necessarily required to mention _@Configuration_ .    if you removed _@ComponentScan_ also then you will get into exception.